# Angular Inter-Directive Communication

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have created the following simple code with several directives (I have experience with Angular only for several months).

I have used unusual way to make some basic inheritance (as You can see from the Directive class), parameters by default (using ||), possibility to insert one element into another (using transclude), have added directory-specific controllers and of course, specified the link function to support DOM events handlers.

Currently I am trying to call function specified in another directory controller through it's scope, but it fails. The error is 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function'.

My target is to call controller's function independently from the DOM structure (the target element could be sibling, parent or child). I have considered also shared service and broadcast events, but it seems not the right way to make the communication.

Why the code doesn't work properly?
Are there any other ways to make it?

Thanks in advance.

HTML

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <component id="button" name="button">
    </component>
    <icon name="icon">
    </icon>
</body>
```

JS

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.directive('icon', function() {
        var directive = new Directive();
        return directive;
    });

    app.directive('button', function() {
        var directive = new Directive();
        return directive;
    });

    function Directive(options) {
        options = options || {};
        this.scope = options.scope || {
            name: '@'
        };
        this.restrict = options.restrict || 'E';
        this.replace = (options.replace != null) ? options.replace : true;
        this.transclude = (options.transclude != null) ? options.transclude : true;
        this.template = options.template || '<div ng-transclude></div>';
        this.controller = function($scope) {
            $scope.focus = function() {
                console.log('focus');
            };
            $scope.outFocus = function() {
                console.log('outFocus');
            };
        };
        this.link = options.link || function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $element.click(function() {
                $scope.focus();
                var _scope = angular.element('#button').scope();
                _scope.outFocus(); // doesn't work
            });
        };
    }
})();
```